# Limit a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move inside of a specific view only

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to recreate the volume bar seen in iOS 11:

[image]

I tried doing that by creating a black (slightly) transparent UIView, and then adding a white subview to it. Through a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` I'm trying to actually give it the functionality I want to give it, though I want to limit that movement so:

- the white bar can only be moved along the Y axis
- The white bar can maximally be moved up to the parents top, not further (same goes for the bottom)

Now the first thing was easy to figure out, however now I need to restrain it so it can't be moved higher or lower then the parent UIView

This is my code so far:

```
let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.barWasDragged))
self.volumeBar.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

 @objc func barWasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began, .ended:
            viewCenter = self.volumeBar.center
        case .changed:
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
            self.volumeBar.center.y = viewCenter!.y + translation.y
        default: break
        }
    }
```

But now, what is the best way to restrain it, can I perhaps just set bounds for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

Thanks.

-- Edit

Just to clarify,

The black bar in the background is my `volumeView`, and de white (draggable) bar is my `volumeBar`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the frame for your `volumeBar`, you can do something like this

```
@objc func barWasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began, .ended:
        viewCenter = self.volumeBar.center
    case .changed:
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
        let newYValue = viewCenter.y + translation.y
        if newYValue > volumeBar.frame.origin.y && newYValue < (volumeBar.frame.origin.y+volumeBar.frame.size.height) {
            self.volumeBar.center.y = newYValue
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `volumeView` is the black background layer in this scenario?

Comment: Nope. It's the control that shows the volume levels. basically the idea is that in your `.changed` state, you only apply translation if it is between the bounds of the volume control

Comment: I've updated the question with my naming scheme, since our difference Is confusing the ****** out of me.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: This works, sort of.. you can still go about 1/3rd over the desired bounds. I'll try to include a GIF